# Alternate element order with Smarty

Tags: html, smarty

I want to alternate whether HTML code A shows before code B based on a boolean.

Somewhat like:

```
{if $switch}B A{else}A B{/if}
```

However, considering A and B are actually long parts of HTML+Smarty code, I don't want to add them twice for the sake of maintainability.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### {capture}
>
> {capture} is used to collect the output of the template between the tags into a variable instead of displaying it. Any content between {capture name='foo'} and {/capture} is collected into the variable specified in the name attribute.

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl)

```
{* template *}

{capture name=parta assign=parta}
    foo
{/capture}

{capture name=partb assign=partb}
    bar
{/capture}

{if $switch}
    {$partb} {$parta}
{else}
    {$parta} {$partb}
{/if}
```

Comment: Wow. Perfectly what I wanted, and I discovered something I'll use elsewhere. Thanks!